# Wordpress: Show archives only from this year

Tags: wordpress, archive, sidebar

I'm trying to show archives in my sidebar but only from this year.

I have this in my sidebar:

```
wp_get_archives( array( 
    'type'  =>  'monthly',
    'limit' =>  '12'
));
```

This works as intended and only gives monthly archive links for the past 12 months. Is there a way I can filter this so it only gets monthly archives for the current year?

For reference, here are the docs for [`wp_get_archives`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wp_get_archives( array( 
    'type'  =>  'yearly',
    'limit' =>  '1'
));
```